# Retrieve base address of a base module from a process

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-address

I have been trying to read a processes memory at a certain address, I have found that it is located at an offset + a modules location. Basically, I have been trying to find out how to get the modules location of a running process, however I have had no success. In order to do this I have been trying to use the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function, however I am getting an error in my code with Module32First where it is returning false, and I cannot figure out what the problem is. Is there any reason it keeps giving me a false return?

```
// CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pid);
HANDLE snapshot_test = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pid);

// Check if the handle is valid
if (snapshot_test != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

    // First module
    MODULEENTRY32 mod_entry;
    mod_entry.dwSize = sizeof(mod_entry);

    if (Module32First(snapshot_test, &mod_entry)) {
        do {
            cout << mod_entry.szModule << endl;
            cout << "test" << endl;
        } while (Module32Next(snapshot_test, &mod_entry));
    }
    else (cout << "module32first error");
}
else (cout << "snapshot error")
```

Comment: As with most Windows API functions, if it fails you can call GetLastError immediately afterwards and then try to use that error code to understand why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TheUndeadFish, I was unaware about that I'll keep that in mind for the future. As for the answer it appears this problem has come up in the past. The Windows documentation really explains this quite poorly.